# How to Add Product in Code Igniter Cart with different Size?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I have a client who needs an E-Commerce site for his Foam Manufacturing Company. I am making this project using Code Igniter.

Here I have a problem. Each Foam has its own custom cutting. For example we need L Shape foam so we have to calculate length,width and Side Length. If we have square shape then we need to measure Width and Height. If we have O shape we need Radius.

I am confused that how I put all this in one Cart. Is this possible to get different Product's with different options and Sizes?

Secondly tell me how can I get all these product's from DB? Because it is not possible for me to get this multiple type of data from DB.

Please help me I am so confused. I have running Short of Time.

Comment: use unique session id to map all the product adding into the cart respective of what ever be there size